# Why was this League of Legends flag declined?

Tags: discussion

In [This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263179/can-you-get-a-hextech-chest-on-a-s-rating-champ/), the asker wants to know if he will earn a chest when his "non elegibility" (A term only used when a Chat Restricted or Recently Banned player meets criteria for receiving a chest, but won't get it because he was recently punished) means that if he gets an S rank (The criteria to get the chest) he will get a chest once his punishment wears off. In other words, he wants to know if he'll get a chest when his "non eligibility" expires, or does he have to meet the criteria again.

One of the answers (Greatwon) simply stated that :

> No.
>
> Once you get a S rating on a specific champion and get a chest, you cannot receive another chest for that champion until the next season.
>
> http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/site/2016-season-update/champion-mastery.html

In other words, it would've been the same as if I was asking how long the Pacman's ability to eat the ghosts lasts, and my answer being "You can eat ghosts when you eat that bigger pellet"

In my opinion, it doesn't answer the question. It answers a question, but not the one that was asked. Why was this flag declined?

Comment: For one, "not eligible" is **not** a league of legends term. It might have specific meaning to you, or be used in a specific way in LoL, but it has a very standardised meaning in every day language. It looks like your assuming the posters meaning without clarification.

Comment: @Timelord64 In the context of the question it only has that meaning. It's the official wording used in the pop-up boxes that originated the question for the asker

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. That answer certainly applies to the linked question. You raise the case that it might not, as there could be other circumstances. But we don't know that. This is a case for the question being clarified, not an answer being deleted or flagged.

Comment: @Oak, your making an assumption that asked is directly quoting. The word, itself, is not official. They didn't invent the word, they just chose it due to its meaning.

Comment: @Timelord64 I never said they invented the word. But they defined it in that context. Similarly how 'OP' can have different meanings, and depending on its context you have totally different informations. If by 'non eligible' they refer to the scenarios where a player has been recently punished with xyz, then that is what non eligible means in that context

Comment: @Oak, and if asker has never seen this use of the word, but knows they have reached a cap, they might still say 'they are not eligible'. Because it is the correct use of the word, and it is the particular choice of words they have chosen. You can not assume the asker has the same understanding as you, nor can you enforce the exact word choice of users.

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like the answer is directly answering the question.  You seem to be assuming a specific scenario, which hasn't been spelled out by the asker, and applying the answer to that hypothetical question.  That's not what Not An Answer flags are for.  They are specifically if an answer makes no attempt to answer the question.  Wrong, or not answering what you think the question is asking, are not what flags are for.  That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: Following that logic I can simply answer anything I'd like - while not actually answering any question - and I wouldn't be breaking any rules; others would've just understood the question differently. Essentially cluttering the .SE with text that adds nothing to the point?

Comment: No, you're twisting my words.  Unless you are *directly* answering the question, it's not an answer.  Based on your (in my opinion, mistaken) interpretation, that answer doesn't do so.  But based on a reasonable reading of the question, it's *extremely* easy to see that the answer in question answers the question.  If you want to try answering questions based on such a twisted interpretation, feel free.  But I and others will be downvoting and flagging them.

Comment: I am intentionally twisting your words. It's the best approach in demonstrative sciences. You pick a case, and you get the general formulaes for that scenario, which then allows you to use it to deduce not only the particular case you had, but all others. Pretty much the basis for Mathemathics, Physics and most of current active fields of exact science studies. With that said, I still don't understand how the answer is to that question. Sure it's nomenclature that is making us diverge in opinions, however it's also that nomenclature that you don't know the terminology of the game in question

Comment: Irrelevant.  The point is, if an answer answers the question **as posed**, it's an answer.  Assume a good faith attempt.  Look at it from a layman's perspective; if it looks like an answer, when you know nothing about the game, then it's an answer.

Comment: Precisely, which is why non laymans should try to shed light in order to improve the dynamic of the situation. In fact, the question was edited and the original asker commented on only my answer as having the awnser he was looking for

Comment: Still irrelevant to the point.  The answer being discussed **is an answer**.  If it doesn't answer what the asker wanted, well, that's on them for not clarifying.

Comment: That's being redundant. Essentially you're saying that I can ask anything. If someone perceives it as something else different than what I wrote, the answer is valid? Where's the logic in that?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you ask a question, and people don't understand it the way you want, that's your fault.  Use your words.  Use them so that people don't get confused.  If people answer based on a misunderstood question, it's *still* an answer.  They are answering in good faith to try to help you.